# View traffic source on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

I noticed there was a sudden spike in traffic in my Google Analytics.

Is there a way to possibly identify where the traffic was from? It only happened on a specific date though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select your date (in the top right of screen) and go to the following menu on Google Analytics: *Traffic sources => All traffic*.

That way, you can see for each source the number of visits for this day.

Answer (score -1):

[Google Analytics] will show you all hits (i.e. 200 from Facebook, 100 from Twitter etc.) from the last month. It won't show you for a specific day, though it will show you your main source of traffic.

I found the only way to get information for each day is by using an analytics app.  Even that only gives you details for all traffic sources for today, yesterday, last week, and last month. I don't think you can get a daily report on how many hits you got from each site.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and may be referring to some other service. Google Analytics can and does show you specific hits from specific sites for specific days.